# require_once dentro helper codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, composer, autoload

Instalei a biblioteca mpdf via composer no codeigniter 2 e fiz um arquivo helper onde eu chamo essa biblioteca para gerar o pdf. Então dentro dessa helper eu chamo o autoload com require_once e funciona perfeitamente localmente. Mas quando subi em produção da erro 500 exatamente nesse require. Já tentei de tudo e nada pra resolver, alguém poderia me orientar?

Comment: Precisa olhar o log de erro do apache,

Comment: @rray mas é por causa de estar chamando de forma errada o arquivo, so precisava saber como referencio de forma correta

Comment: Cadê o código!?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic não é erro no código e sim em não localizar o arquivo autoload dentro de vendor, ou não é compativel com versão do php. Acho que suspeito do que possa ser, em desenvolvimento localhost meu servidor é com php 7 e no servidor online é 5.3 e a biblioteca mpdf é na versão 7.1

Comment: @ThiagoMoreira então é a versão ... !!! OK

Comment: **é erro de código sim**. Não se usa _helper_ pra carregar biblioteca.